# fgetcsv fails to read line ending in mac formatted csv file, any better solution?

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I was parsing a csv file using php with fgetcsv function. It parsed all content in a line, later i found, csv contains carraige return as "\r". I saw - it was reported as php bug before. I've solved this by setting php runtime configuration which is -

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", "1");
```

is there any more solution or is this the right way?

Thanks

Comment: You should answer your own question here so you can close the question.

Comment: For future reference this has to be done BEFORE the call to `fopen`.  I added it between the call to `fopen` and the call to `fgetcsv` for testing and it didn't work.  I'll never see that twenty minutes every again.  :-)

Comment: @ScottWarren - I cannot believe I have not read this until now.  For the past YEAR I could not figure out why my CSV import in Store Locator Plus was not working on osx files!  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This should default to '1' in PHP instead of us trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 37):

Setting `auto_detect_line_endings` is explicitly recommended by the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

However, I cannot fathom why you would want to delimit lines with `\r` in 2010. If possible, convert them to the UNIX-style `\n`.

Comment: My client gave me a file which contains \r. I asked him which OS version he uses, he told he uses leopard and office 2008. I am building a plugin for them where there will have many end user, so i'm trying to build this cross platform.

Comment: In my case, the user was on Mac OS (10.9, Maverick) using MS Office Excel 2011.

Comment: In my case it was Excel 2013 on Windows 7.

Comment: Now it's 2016 and I still get people uploading this kind of files, generated by current Excel on Mac OS.

Comment: It's 2018 now - _Still_ getting garbage CSV files from clients with unpredictable line endings; `auto_detect_line_endings` is pure magic!

Answer (score 5):

`\r` line endings are created by Microsoft Excel when saving as a CSV file, so there is not much getting around that if you are starting with an Excel spreadsheet.

Using `auto_detect_line_endings` works fine, or you can normalize line endings with `preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", "\n", $subject);`